# How to use find_all with BeautifulSoup to search for multiple tags or classes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping some HTML that is formatted like this:

```
<div class="doccontent">
<h3> Section Title 1 </h3>
<div class="line"> My first line </div>
<div class="line> My second line </div>
<div class="linenumber"> text i don't need </div>

<h3> Section Title 2 </h3>
<div class="line"> My third line </div>
<div class="chapter">Chapter four</div>
<div class="line> My fourth line </div>
</div>
```

I only want to capture the h3 and class="line" text. I tried two ways. The first:

```
for lines in full_text:
    for booktitle in lines.find("h3"):
        linesArr.append(booktitle)
    for line in lines.find_all(class_='line'):
        linesArr.append(line)
```

This appends all booktitles to the beginning of the list, then starts working on the lines.

The second:

```
for lines in full_text:
    for line in lines.find_all(['h3', class_="line"]):
        linesArr.append(line)
```

The second seems more promising to me, but there is a syntax error.The BS4 documentation doesn't cover how to search for a list of tags and classes. Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: Try `.select('h3, .line')`. You could use `find_all` with a lambda, but that would be more complicated.

Comment: @t.m.adam:  I guess it is: `.select('h3 div.line')`. It is not?

Comment: @daniherrera No, we need the comma to select either h3 tags or tags that have a 'line' calss. without the comma it would select tags that have a 'line' calss and are children of a h3 tag.

Comment: @t.m.adam this worked. I changed find_all to select('h3, .line') and script captured data from both those elements. It's unfortunate I missed this explanation of select in the BS4 documentation, but it's because I was looking at find and find_all. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help! Since the answer from QHarr solves the problem you could mark it as accepted. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: hi @t.m.adam it has sense. nice work. Post as answer in order to vote it up.

Comment: @daniherrera Thank you, but I won't post an answer because it would be very similar to QHarr's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can use css Or syntax to specify multiple css selectors and pass those to select

```
data = [item.text for item in soup.select("h3 , .line")]
```